# Downgrade to 4.13 or upgrade to 4.18 from 4.15 kernel

Tags: upgrade, kernel, updates, downgrade

I had Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4 but I need TCP BBR and I read that TCP BBR is present in kernel since version 4.9 so I installed the following:

`sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04`

So when running *uname -a*, I have now 4.15.0-38-generic.

But now because of this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1783822, I need either to downgrade to 4.13 or to update to 4.18 kernel.

Maybe, I should mention that when I run *dpkg -l | grep linux*, I see many 4.13 and 4.15 linux-image and linux-signed-image packages.

Could you, please, tell what is the best way to solve my problem and at the same time not to have problems with future updates?

Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer a tool called ukuu

It allows upgrade and downgrade of any mainstream kernel available.

Install it by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

Please note this may not always provide super stable releases of your kernel, but I've never had issues

Comment: You're welcome!